# Is there an issue with PIL library?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-imaging-library

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from PIL import Image, UnidentifiedImageError
from io import BytesIO


search = input("Enter: ")
params = {"q": search}
url = "https://www.bing.com/images/search"
r = requests.get(url, params=params)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
links = soup.findAll("a", {"class": "iusc"})

for item in links:
    img_obj = requests.get("https://www.bing.com"+item.attrs["href"])
    title = item.attrs["href"].split("/")[-1]
    try:
        img = PIL.Image.open(BytesIO(img_obj.content))
        img.save("./scraped_images/" + title, img.format)
    except PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: 
        print(item)
```

Error :

```
Enter: pizza
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "images.py", line 21, in <module>
img = PIL.Image.open(BytesIO(img_obj.content))
NameError: name 'PIL' is not defined
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "images.py", line 23, in <module>
except PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: 
NameError: name 'PIL' is not defined
```

Also note that I am working in a virtualenvironment. Maybe an issue is there. Can someone tell how to solve this error?
Also if I don't include PIL.unidentifiedImageError in except: code gives an error for this unidentifiedImageError.

Comment: `PIL.Image.open` --> `Image.open`

Comment: if you `... import Image` then use `Image.open()`

Comment: You never imported `PIL` itself, hence `PIL` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You have imported `Image` and `UnidentifiedImageError` from the PIL package but not PIL itself. There are two ways you can solve this. Either you say at the top

```
import PIL

#your code
```

Or you leave out the PIL at the place where you load the image:

```
img = PIL.Image.open(BytesIO(img_obj.content))
```

Comment: I did this. Now in output I am getting only links. The images arent being saved :(((

Answer (score 0):

There's no issue with the PIL library, just modify your code as follows:

```py
for item in links:
    img_obj = requests.get("https://www.bing.com"+item.attrs["href"])
    title = item.attrs["href"].split("/")[-1]
    try:
        img = Image.open(BytesIO(img_obj.content))
        img.save("./scraped_images/" + title, img.format)
    except UnidentifiedImageError: 
        print(item)
```

Remember that you're importing the Image and UnidentifiedImageError objects, at that point Python doesn't know what PIL is because you haven't imported PIL or defined it elsewhere.

Comment: did this, in output now I am gettting only links, not one single image is being saved.. :(

Answer (score 0):

You aren't importing `PIL`, you're importing from `PIL`, so you shouldn't prefix its members with `PIL`. I.e.., replace `img = PIL.Image.open(BytesIO(img_obj.content))` with `img = Image.open(BytesIO(img_obj.content))` and `except PIL.UnidentifiedImageError:` with `except UnidentifiedImageError:`.

Comment: did this, in output now I am gettting only links, not one single image is being saved.. :(